# Django query between startdate and duration

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Im working on a Django project and I have to make a query that returns all my  record that are active at the moment. The query must be between(startdate, startdate + duration)

I got this query so far, but I don't know how to query startdate + duration < datetime.now()

View:

```
def home(request):
  active_tasks = Task.objects.all().filter(start_time__lte=datetime.now())
  context = {'active_tasks' : active_tasks}
  return render(request, "main/home.html", context)
```

Task model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
  start_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
  duration = models.IntegerField(default=10)
```

Comment: Is there a good reason you store a duration in your model instead of an end time? An end time would be significantly easier to query. You could still have a duration as a calculated property if you need to display it somewhere.

Comment: He could somehow use django annotation, for example the postgresql has a lot of extra function for datetime so something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432926/aggregate-difference-between-datetime-fields-in-djano would be possible. But I think its an overkill

Comment: I used a duration of minutes, because its easier to fill in a form then to fill in an enddate everytime. And the tasks only take a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several defects. First, it's not clear for us what unit does `duration` have, days, months, years, minutes?

I assume you were using days, but you couldn't query that because you need to convert `start_time + duration` to datetime and treat it as end time for each record, which is not possible in single query. As @solarissmoke mentioned, you should store the `end_time` instead. You could keep the `duration` field if you want, but you could also use a [property method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193556/how-do-python-properties-work) to calculate it.

Also, your field definition `start_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())` would not work, because the default time would only be evaluated once when django starts(when the model is loaded). It's a common mistake that new django developers make. You should change it to:

```
start_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

This case, `datetime.now` would be treated as a function object and be called every time you create a new object, which is what you want. Note that django has the built in flag to do that: [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add).

Check [this SO answer on more detailed explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771676/django-datetime-issues-default-datetime-now)

Comment: Ill change my datetime.now() to datetime.now. Im using a duration of minutes. I choose for this, because its easier to fill in a form instead of an end date. I know its alot more difficult to query now, but isn't there a solution for this?

Comment: As I said, just add a field called `end_time`, so when you save the model, calculate the `end_time` from `start_time` and `duration` and fill the field. Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'll try to implement this in a bit, first I have some other stuff to do. I'll report back.

Comment: Now im trying to calculate the endtime with the starttime and duration. You said you can do it when you save the model. But isnt there a possibility to do this in de model it self?

Comment: What do you mean `do this in the model itself`?

Comment: In the form to fill in I only want to have start_time and duration. Then the model calculates the end_time field it self. It that possible?

Comment: You could save the form `obj = form.save()`, do the calculation in the views, then do `obj.end_time = calculated_end_time`, `obj.save()`, right?

Comment: I think I'll go with that. I think it would be nicer if the model it self calculates the end date, but the view can also handle that I suppose.

Comment: You can do that, but if your model calculates the end date but not storing it, we came back to the problem of not being able to do the query, right?

Comment: In fact, I would rather you store `start_time` and `end_time`, but calculate `duration` in model instead.

Comment: The model can calculate the enddate indeed, but then we are at my point again. I rather dont want to input a datetime for the endate, because filling in a duration is much easier.

Comment: Well im trying to do the `obj = form.save()` ,  but I get an error: `obj.end_date = obj.start_date + timedelta(
AttributeError: 'Task' object has no attribute 'start_date'`

Comment: No, you still let user fill in duration, but in views you only store `start_time` and `end_time`. You should make your project more flexible as a common practice, you shouldn't always model exactly what the user input is, even if it's a `ModelForm`, think outside the box.

Comment: Stackoverflow is no place for interactive exercise. I can only help you so much on the general thinking, you should be able to figure out the debug stuff yourself. Your variable name is wrong, not `start_date`, it's `start_time`.

Comment: Haha wow, I didnt see that. Well I thank you for your help and I hope i'll work it out.