# How to annotate a difference of datetime in days

Tags: django, datetime, django-annotate, django-database-functions

I have a `Booking` model that has `start` and `end` datetime fields. I want to know how many days a booking covers. I can do this in Python but I need this value for further annotations.

Here's what I've tried:

```
In [1]: Booking.objects.annotate(days=F('end')-F('start'))[0].days
Out[1]: datetime.timedelta(16, 50400)
```

There are a few problems here:

- I want an integer (or other number type I can use in calculations) of days as the output, not a timedelta. Setting output_field doesn't do anything meaningful here.
- My sums are based on date**times**. Subtractions like this, without removing the time could lead to the whole number of days being off.

In Python I would do `(end.date() - start.date()).days + 1`. How can I do that in-database, preferably through the ORM (eg database functions), but a `RawSQL` would suffice to get this out the door?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8432926

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've written a couple of database functions to cast and truncate the dates to solve both problems under PostgreSQL. The `DATE_PART` and `DATE_TRUNC` internal function I'm using are DB-specific ☹

```
from django.db.models import Func

class DiffDays(Func):
    function = 'DATE_PART'
    template = "%(function)s('day', %(expressions)s)"

class CastDate(Func):
    function = 'date_trunc'
    template = "%(function)s('day', %(expressions)s)"
```

Then I can:

```
In [25]: Booking.objects.annotate(days=DiffDays(CastDate(F('end'))-CastDate(F('start'))) + 1)[0].days
Out[25]: 18.0
```

Answer (score 12):

There is another, easy solution of this problem. You can use:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractDay
```

and then:

```
Booking.objects.annotate(days=(ExtractDay(F('end')-F('start'))+1))[0].days
```

Comment: this only works in case the month and year have same value. Otherwise it will fail

Comment: Hi @rawat I have tested with different months and years, it works correctly, does not fail. I'm using django 3.2. Please confirm, thanks..

Comment: @MarcinEl great answer. It works even when year and month are different, confirming

Comment: The results are probably not uniform across all available database options. For example ExtractDay will throw an error if the DB doesn't support native duration/interval fields (eg. sqlite).

Comment: This does not work the way you think. It gets the day value (2022-01-02 gives 2 same as 2033-03-02) so If the dates are in the same month and year, it will return the correct value. Otherwise, you get a wrong value.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been long but in case someone else is looking into it, this is what worked for me

```
from django.db.models import DurationField, ExpressionWrapper, F, DateTimeField
from django.db.models.functions import Extract

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    duration=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('end_date') - F('start_date'),
        output_field=DurationField()
    )
).annotate(
    duration_in_days=Extract('duration', 'day')
)
```

Also for my case I was trying to get the difference between current date and a field, I used the following

```
from django.utils import timezone
today = timezone.now().date()
qs.annotate(
        duration=ExpressionWrapper(
            Cast(today, DateTimeField()) - F('date'),
            output_field=DurationField()
        )
    ).annotate(
        duration_in_days=Extract('duration', 'day')
    )
```

Comment: Interesting idea. The *potential* problem with duration is it does not count calendar dates, just 24h periods. It really depends on the use-case to know if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **MYSQL** database, You could do it using ***Custom DB Function*** as,

```
from django.db.models.functions import Func


class TimeStampDiff(Func):
    class PrettyStringFormatting(dict):
        def __missing__(self, key):
            return '%(' + key + ')s'

    def __init__(self, *expressions, **extra):
        unit = extra.pop('unit', 'day')
        self.template = self.template % self.PrettyStringFormatting({"unit": unit})
        super().__init__(*expressions, **extra)

    function = 'TIMESTAMPDIFF'
    template = "%(function)s(%(unit)s, %(expressions)s)"
```

**Usage**

```
from django.db.models import F, IntegerField

booking_queryset = Booking.objects.annotate(
    days=TimeStampDiff(F('start'), F('end'), output_field=IntegerField()))
if booking_queryset.exist():
    print(booking_queryset[0].__dict__)
```