# How to calculate number of days, when two DateFields are given? Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Leave(models.Model):
    ...
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The above are the two date fields which are defined in my models.py.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from .forms import LeaveRequestForm
from django.shortcuts import 
from .models import Leave
...
def get_days(request):
    data = Leave.objects.all()
    for x in data :
        if x.employee_ID == request.user.username:
            d1 = x.from_date
            d2 = x.to_date
            days = d2 - d1
    return render(request,"status.html", days)
```

The above code is my trial on getting the number of days.

Here, my model is `Leave` and my form is `LeaveRequestForm`. In my HTML file to get the number of days I use `{{ from_date|timesince:to_date }}`, this works but i want to deduct this number of days from a number.

base : I'm working on a leave-management project. If a user asks a leave for 5days and he is eligible for 10days. His balance leaves should be equal to 5.

How do I achieve this with the views?

Comment: I answered a similar question here, [implementation of **`TIMESTAMPDIFF`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790498/how-to-implement-timestampdiff-of-mysql-in-django)

Comment: also this, [difference in days- Django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51778823/8283848)

Comment: @JPG I'm not using MYSQL btw, I want a view not a model entry so that my db in dbsqlite3 doesn't effect and i can use it in a template.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar   I use `{{ from_date|timesince:to_date }}` to get number of days, but I need to subtract this from a number. This isn't working

Comment: @Jose So, you may use a template variable. Or you can also use a model method. Here's the way to use a template variable [https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070414/3968623](here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [**`property`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) in model as

```
from django.db import models


class Leave(models.Model):
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def date_diff(self):
        return (self.to_date - self.from_date).days
```

and in your template you could  use it as **`{{ leave_object.date_diff }}`**

Comment: So, now can I subtract the number of days from a number. Like `{{ 10 -leave_object.date_diff }} ` ?

Comment: Yes. You can do that

Comment: that's not happening `Could not parse the remainder: ' - x.date_diff' from '10 - x.date_diff'`

Comment: Dhanyavad mere bhai!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `d2 - d1` is a timedelta object which has an integer property `days`.

So you need to write `days = (d2 - d1).days` in your python code, and you will get an `int` which you can subtract from whatever you need.

Comment: in my html file I've given it as {{days}}. But there's no change.