# Django F expression on datetime objects

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-queryset

My model is:

```
class Test():
   date1 = models.DateTimeField()
   date2 = models.DateTimeField()
```

I can find out objects whose `date2` is greater than `date1`, using the following query:

```
Test.objects.filter(date2__gt=F('date1'))
```

I would like to find all the objects whose `date2` is greater than `date1` by one year.
How can I find out objects based on difference between `date1` and `date2`?

Comment: Don't have an install handy to try, but what about `Test.objects.annotate(next_year=F('date1') + timedelta(days=365)).filter(next_year__gt=F('date2'))` ? Or doing a subtraction of the two dates in the annotation expression.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**General Solution:**

You can `annotate` the date difference and then check this against the `timedelta(days=365)` (pretty close to what @Anonymous suggests in his comment):

```
Test.objects.annotate(
    duration=F('date2') - F('date1')
).filter(duration__gt=timedelta(days=365))
```

---

**PostgreSQL Specific Solution:**

If you are using `PostgreSQL`, there is another option derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432926/aggregate-difference-between-datetime-fields-in-djano/35721409#35721409):

```
from django.db.models import F, Func

Test.objects.annotate(
    duration = Func(F('date2'), F('date1'), function='age')
).filter(duration__gt=timedelta(days=365))
```

Comment: If I use Test.objects.annotate(duration=F('date2') - F('date1')), I am getting some decimal values at queryset. What are those values?

Comment: @MahabuburRahamanMelon are you using MySQL by any chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483363/python-mysqldb-returns-datetime-date-and-decimal?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Yes I am using MySQL. Is that a problem for this solution?

Comment: Tried using `annotate(duration=F('end_time') - F('start_time')).filter(duration__gt=timedelta(0,299))` but I received an error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: @sytech Seems to be a problem elsewhere in your code, unrelated to this thread. Maybe with your migrations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353649/django-migrate-error-typeerror-expected-string-or-bytes-like-object

Comment: If "greater by one year" means "year part of the date is greater by 1". Then this solution will not correctly work for: `Jan01-Feb28` on the Leap year (2020-01-01 .. 2020-02-28), and for `Mar01-Dec31` on a year before leap year (2019-03-01 .. 2019-12-31). Se my answer with alternate approach that can handle leap years

Comment: It also will not work correctly with `timezone.activate(); qs.filter(...)` in timezone `Europe/Kiev`, for `date1=2010-03-27 23:30`, `date2=2011-03-28 00:01`, because delta will be less than 365 days: `kyiv = pytz.timezone('Europe/Kiev'); kyiv.localize(datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 28, 0, 1)) - kyiv.localize(datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 27, 23, 30)) == datetime.timedelta(364, 84660)` (caused by different dates to switch to DST on those years)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`__date` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#date) and [`TruncDate` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncDate) together:

```py
from django.db.models import DateField, ExpressionWrapper, F
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate
Test.obejcts.filter(
    date2__date__gt=ExpressionWrapper(
        TruncDate(F('date1')) + datetime.timedelta(days=365),
        output_field=DateField(),
    ),
)
```

If what you really need is something like `date1 = 2019-05-14`, `date2 > 2020-05-14`. Then this approach is not always correct because leap year have 366 days. This issue can be solved using `Trunc` and `Extract` functions together. Different approaches are possible... For example:

```py
from django.db.models import DateField, ExpressionWrapper, F
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate, ExtractDay

date_field = DateField()

YEAR = timedelta(days=365)
LEAP_YEAR = timedelta(days=366)

shifted_date1 = ExpressionWrapper(
    TruncDate(F('date1')) + YEAR,
    output_field=date_field,
)

leap_shifted_date1 = ExpressionWrapper(
    TruncDate(F('date1')) + LEAP_YEAR,
    output_field=date_field,
)


qs = Test.objects.filter(
    (
        # It's ok to add 365 days if...
        Q(date2__date__gt=shifted_date1)
        &
        (
            # If day of month after 365 days is the same...
            Q(date1__day=ExtractDay(shifted_date1))
            |
            # Or it's 29-th of February
            Q(
                date1__month=2,
                date1__day=29,
            )
        )
    )
    |
    Q(
        # Use 366 days for other cases
        date2__date__gt=leap_shifted_date1,
    )
)
```

P.S. If you have `USE_TZ = True` and performing queries in specific timezone (e.g use `timezone.activate(...)` before 
executing querysets), then it's important to do `TruncDate` **before** adding `timedelta`, because doing `TruncDate(F('date1')+timedelta(...))` may give incorrect results in countries where switch to "Daylight saving time" is performed on different dates each year. For example:

- Some country switched to DST time on `2019-03-31` in year 2019 and will switch `2020-03-29` in year 2020.
- Local time on `2019-03-30 23:30` is not using DST yet.
- Adding 366 days (because next year is a leap year) to it will give `2020-03-30 23:30 "non-DST"`, so after "normalization" this datetime will become
  `2020-03-31 00:30 "DST"`
- Using `TruncDate` before adding timedelta solves the issue, because [`TruncDate` casts value to date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncDate).

Extra info: some countries are switching to DST on a fixed dates e.g. on 1-st of February each year, others might be  switching "on last Sunday of March" which might be a different date each year.

```py
import pytz
import datetime

kyiv.localize(datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 28, 0, 1)) - kyiv.localize(datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 28, 0, 1))
# `datetime.timedelta(364, 82800)` is less than 365 days
```

P.P.S. last seconds of "**leap second** year" (`2016-12-31 23:59:60.999`)  might have been affected by ordering of TruncDate/timedelta-shift too, but "fortunately" most databases do not support leap seconds, and python's `datetime.datetime` 
also lacks this feature