# Django QuertySet.annotate() received non-expression - how to add a derived field based on model field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

First time with Django. Trying to add an annotation to queryset:

```
class EnrollmentManager(models.Manager.from_queryset(EnrollmentCustomQuerySet)):
  COURSE_DURATION = datetime.timedelta(days=183)

  def get_queryset(self):
      """Overrides the models.Manager method"""
      lookback = make_aware(datetime.datetime.today() - self.COURSE_DURATION)
      qs = super(EnrollmentManager, self).get_queryset().annotate( \
              is_expired=(Value(True)), output_field=models.BooleanField())
      return qs
```

At the moment I am just trying to add an extra 'calculated' field on the returned queryset, which is hard-coded to True and the attribute/field should be called `is_expired`.

If I can get that to work, then Value(True) needs to be a derived value based on this expression:

```
F('enrolled') < lookback
```

But since 'enrolled' is a database field and `lookback` is calculated, how will I be able to do that?

**Note**

I tried this, which executes without throwing the error:

```
qs = super(EnrollmentManager, self).get_queryset().annotate( \
         is_expired=(Value(True, output_field=models.BooleanField())))
```

and in the shell I can see it:

```
Enrollment.objects.all()[0].is_expired -> returns True
```

and I can add it to the serializer:

```
class EnrollmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  is_active = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  is_current = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  is_expired = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  COURSE_DURATION = datetime.timedelta(days=183)

  class Meta:
    model = Enrollment
    fields = ('id', 'is_active', 'is_current', 'is_expired')

  def get_is_expired(self, obj):
    return obj.is_expired
```

So it is possible...but how can I replace my hard-coded 'True" with a calculation?

**UPDATE**

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate-args-kwargs), it states:

"Annotates each object in the QuerySet with the provided list of query expressions. An expression may be a simple value, a reference to a field on the model (or any related models), or an aggregate expression (averages, sums, etc.) that has been computed over the objects that are related to the objects in the QuerySet."

**A simple value** - so, not a simple COMPUTED value then?

That makes me think this is not possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a pretty good use-case for a `Case` expression. I suggest getting as familiar as you can with [these expression tools](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/), they're very helpful!

I haven't tested this, but it should work. I'm assuming enrolled is a tz-aware datetime for when they first enrolled...

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value

def get_queryset(self):
    """Overrides the models.Manager method"""
    lookback = make_aware(datetime.datetime.today() - self.COURSE_DURATION)
    qs = super(EnrollmentManager, self).get_queryset().annotate(
        is_expired=Case(
            When(
                enrolled__lt=lookback,
                then=Value(True)
            ),
            default=Value(False),
            output_field=models.BooleanField()
        )
    )
```

You also don't have to pre-calculate the lookback variable. Check out ExpressionWrappers and [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890131/django-f-expression-on-datetime-objects) that addresses this.

```
ExpressionWrapper(
    TruncDate(F('date1')) + datetime.timedelta(days=365),
    output_field=DateField(),
)
```