# Django - modify a field value just for filtering purpose

Tags: django

I want to modify `some_date_field` value just for filtering purpose.
Like using `models.Lookup` or `models.Transform` but I dont want to make a raw sql expression.

For instance, using a raw ms sql expression I could write:

```
WHERE CONVERT(date, FORMAT(some_date_field, '2021MMdd')) >= @some_var
```

But I how I can do that with Django?

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_date_field = models.DateField()

def replace_year(value):
    return value.replace(year=2021) 

SomeModel.objects.filter(
    # replace_year(some_date_field)__gte=some_var
)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SomeModel.objects.filter({whatever you want to filter}).update(some_date_field={date_value})

if you have any issues see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update

Comment: Sorry for my inaccuracy. I mean I don't want to update db. I want to customize field's value just for filter. For example in a raw SQL i can do "where dateadd(day, 1, some_date_field) = @some_value"

Comment: If I understood you correctly from comment above you want to ""filter all the records where next day is today". So you're looking for the records which have the date of yesterday.
For that you can just use regular filter with datetime and timedelta:

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

yesterday = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=1)
SomeModel.objects.filter(some_date_field__gt=yesterday)

will bring you all objects where the next day is today or later. you can switch gt to lt if you want the next day to be today or earlier.

Comment: so as I understand I can't transform left side of condition as I wish? I can use just default simple methods such as __year __gte and etc?

Comment: what if I have `birth_date` field and I want to show "all birth days in next 7 days". So I'd like to transform birth year by current one and then use __range. How I can do it by `filter()`?

Comment: Exactly, filter is a function that expects a QuerySet (django object).
You can see all existing methods of building a QuerySet here:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/

For your second comment - will have to combine the gt and lt function like so:
SomeModel.objects.filter(birth_date__gt=today, birth_date__lt=today+timdelta(days=7))

Comment: It won't work, because year of `birth_date` is the past. You need to do smth with it before filtering

Comment: It's an equation - it doesn't matter which side you work on.
the 3 options you have are:
1. filter on changed value (for example if you want all birthdays the happened at least a year ago you can use "SomeModel.objects.filter(birthday__gt=today - timedelta(days=365))"
2. change the values in the DB (with update as shown in my answer), then filter on them
3. Use F() object like so: 
"from django.db.models import F
SomeObject.objects.filter(birthday__gt=F('birthday')-timedelta(days=375))

the third is closest to what you want - it creates a query and changed the fetched values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to bulk update all of the objects returned by a queryset and you are using Django 2.2 or greater you can use 'bulk_update'.

See here: [Django Bulk Update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update)

If you are dynamically updating values based off of another field check out F expressions they can be used with an 'update' on querysets.

See here: [Update dynamically with F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)

Something to note though, this won't use ModelClass.save method (so if you have some logic inside it won't be triggered).

Take a look at [these answers here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890131/django-f-expression-on-datetime-objects)

Comment: Sorry for my inaccuracy. I mean I don't want to update db. I want to customize field's value just for filter. For example in a raw SQL i can do "where dateadd(day, 1, some_date_field) = @some_value"

Answer (score 0):

you can use `filter()` and `update()` methods in django

Assuming we need to filter some known year which is the `old_date` variable and the new value contains in the `new_date` variable

```
# defing mehod to filter and update new date
def update_date(old_date, new_date):
    SomeModel.objects.filter(some_date_field=old_date).update(some_date_field=new_date)
    return None
```

you can find some examples using this [link](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/django+update+object).

Hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: Sorry for my inaccuracy. I mean I don't want to update db. I want to customize field's value just for filter. For example in a raw SQL i can do "where dateadd(day, 1, some_date_field) = @some_value"

Comment: Just for clarification, you just want to filter all the records where the year is 2021 right?

Comment: No, e.g. "filter all the records where next day is today"

Comment: In a raw SQL I can apply any custom function to the left side of condition

Comment: I feel like you can use the filtering option like this, which is `today` is a variable that contains the date you want to filter.
`SomeModel.objects.filter(some_date_field=today)`

Comment: If you want to customize using raw queries please visit [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/)